# Following Apple 'Food Tracker' tutorial for Xcode - can't get button to change label text

Tags: swift, xcode

I'm following [official iOS Apps tutorial](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/referencelibrary/GettingStarted/DevelopiOSAppsSwift/ConnectTheUIToCode.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015214-CH22-SW1) to make a basic Single View Application in Xcode.

Literally all we have done so far is:

- Added a label to the UI and set initial text to 'Meal name:'
- Added a textbox to the UI
- Added a button to the UI

Then we've added some very simple code to the View Controller declaring the label as an outlet and a button action which, when invoked, should change the label's text to `Default Text`.

My ViewController code is now identical to the tutorial code namely:

```swift
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //MARK: Properties

    @IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
    @IBOutlet weak var mealNameLabel: UILabel!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    }

    //MARK: Actions

    @IBAction func setDefaultLabelText(_ sender: UIButton) {
        mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text"
    }
}
```

The problem is that when I press the button in simulator, I get an error message saying an implicitly unwrapped optional value is nil. (app launches fine, it's just when pressing the button)

As I understand it this means something is blank that can't be, but the only optionals I have are:

- The textbox, which isn't blank because before I press the button I write 'biscuits' or something in it
- The label text, which isn't blank because it's set to 'Meal name:' by default

I really can't work out what supposedly has a nil value that is triggering this error?

Answer (score 1):

> As I understand it this means something is blank that can't be

No , This means you need to make sure outlet

```
mealNameLabel.text = "Default Text" // here mealNameLabel is nil
```

is connected to the label in IB

Comment: Thank you, I thought they were connected as I had dragged the UI elements into the text editor to create the outlets/actions in the first place. But turns out yeah they still weren't connected!